# how to convert java jks keystore to pkcs12 certificate programatically?

Tags: java, keystroke, pfx, pkcs#12

Is there is any that i can convert ava jks keystore to pkcs12 certificate programatically?

Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html). You should be able to do it with it.

Oh, wait... you cannot convert a keystore to a certificate... what you can do is get a certificate from the keystore and convert it.